# Windows Batch: wget to download Nirsoft tools - leads to corrupt files

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, wget, aria2

As I made a batch file to update [NirSoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/) tools, I had a strange experience using `wget`.

First I downloaded a text file with pad links:

```
wget http://www.nirsoft.net/pad/pad-links.txt --backups=20 --append-output=C:\Path\Update\LOG\Nirsoft\%Timestamp%_NirSoft.log
```

After, I used [fart-js](https://github.com/jonshipman/fart-js) to delete rows I did not need from the `pad-links.txt` file. Also I used that program to change the download links to `https://www.nirsoft.net/utils`, and change the file extensions to `.zip`.

```
fart ".\pad-links.txt" "http://www.nirsoft.net/pad" "http://www.nirsoft.net/utils" | tee --append C:\Path\Update\LOG\Nirsoft\%Timestamp%_NirSoft.log
```

and

```
fart ".\pad-links.txt" ".xml" ".zip" | tee --append C:\Path\Update\LOG\Nirsoft\%Timestamp%_NirSoft.log
```

After, to download the programs, I used:

```
wget --timestamping --input-file=C:\Path\UtilSuit\NirLauncher\Download\pad-links.txt --append-output=C:\Path\Update\LOG\Nirsoft\%Timestamp%_NirSoft.log
```

Having a look at the log file I found out that not all programs are stored in this location. For example `WirelessKeyView` is stored in `https://www.nirsoft.net/toolsdownload/wirelesskeyview.zip`.

Trying to get this file with `wget` leads to downloaded corrupt files at size of 4kb. The same with `cURL` and `aria2`. When I download it with `Mozilla`, or `IDM`, I have no problems to get the file. So I tried out `wget --auth-no-challenge` or `wget  --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 …"`

I also tried `cliget`, the `wget/aria2/curl` lines it produced while normal downloading with Mozilla.

```
wget --header 'Host: www.nirsoft.net' --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0' --header 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' --header 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' --referer 'https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wirelesskeyview.html' --header 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' --header 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' --header 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' --header 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' --header 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' --header 'DNT: 1' --header 'Sec-GPC: 1' 'https://www.nirsoft.net/toolsdownload/wirelesskeyview.zip' --output-document 'wirelesskeyview.zip'
```

I googled and found [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312689/downloading-certain-files-using-powershell-produce-corrupt-files) for `powershell`, (same error), but cannot reproduce the working answer in batch, (I am not familiar with powershell scripting).

So how is is possible to download the single `wirelesskey.zip` file with `wget`/`curl` or `aria2` in a batch script?

A workaround I found out is downloading it directly from [the pad Panel](https://www.nirsoft.net/panel/wirelesskeyview.exe) but I want the `.zip-file`, including the updated `.chm-file`, and also the 64-bit versions, if available.

One more note, within my anti-virus tool the nirsoft site is exempted from scanning, so that is not the answer.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aah, this one is simple. If you look at the actual page downloaded, it's called "403.html". So, let's open it. The first thing that strikes you is this:

```
<title>Error 403: Missing HTTP referer in the HTTP request</title>
```

So, the server wants a Referer header. Sure, let's give it one:

```
$ wget --referer foo <URL>
```

And it downloads the zip file correctly as expected.

Now, really, the server should not be returning a HTTP 200 response with a file called 403. It really should have sent back a HTTP 403 response. But what can you do? There's broken servers everywhere

Comment: Great, thank you, this helps a lot. Just tried it out and it works. Never heard about you can use foo in this context. The misleading 403 error message I also found out using the https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/http-header-live/ addon. Also downloading another file (see reference topic) https://www.nirsoft.net/toolsdownload/netpass-x64.zip leads to this error. Thanks a lot!